# Image URL from an XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xml-parsing

Hi i am parsing an Xml and gets the data in NSSTring from  the description tag as follows.

```
NSString *Descree= [eleme.description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n\t"]];
NSLog(@"Here- %@",Descree);
```

i find the following result in console.

```
<span style="float:left"><img src="http://www.thtfjhj.net/contents/albumsth/57.jpg" /></span><p ><b></b></p>
```

From this I need to extract the image URL alone.

```
http://www.thtfjhj.net/contents/albumsth/57.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml contains html content within.

So it would be better if u use html parsing, to extract the required fields.

Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) to do it.

If the html contains multiple img tags, you can fetch each contents using html parsing.

Comment: Is there any other way to get this

Comment: have u gone through the tutorial..?

Answer (score 0):

plz use NSXMLParser to parse xml data